# What is the Scala syntax for instantiating using a specific implementation?

Tags: scala

Suppose I have the following trait

```
trait Market {
  def getCurrency: String
}
```

With the following implementation

```
class MarketImpl extends Market {
  override def getCurrency = "USD"
}
```

I have another abstract class as follows

```
abstract class TraitTest extends Market  {
}
```

What is the syntax for instantiating TraitTest using the MarketImpl implementation?  Conceptually something like the following

```
new TraitTest with MarketImpl
```

Although the above does not work because MarketImpl is not a trait

Comment: Why do you not extend `MarketImpl` when you need its behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've hit the single class inheritance limit of Scala (and Java). You can fix it using instance composition/aggregation (in the same way you would using Java):

```
abstract class TraitTest extends Market {
    def getCurrency = market.getCurrency
    val market: Market
}
```

and then you instantiate:

```
val myTraitTest = new TraitTest {
                    val market = new MarketImpl
                  }

scala> myTraitTest.getCurrency
res1: String = USD
```

Answer (score 4):

Both `TraitTest` and `MarketImpl` are classes. Scala cannot inherit from multiple classes. You should refactor your code, e.g. making `TraitTest` a trait. Then you could write `new MarketImpl with TraitTest`.

Answer (score 0):

Make `MarketImpl` a `trait` if you plan to instantiate it together with other classes.